# My modified answer is worthy of undeletion?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, specific-answer

I think my recently modified answer is worthy of undeletion; see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51396467/5732431

Personally, I only care about the solution -- how it runs;
everyone else, on the other hand, _ D E L E T E S _ anything
that's not simple, sweet, and easy to understand.

Comment: Looks like it should've been deleted.  If you copied the same answer to multiple questions, not only is that a strong indication that the question(s) are a dupe and should be flagged as such, but diamond moderators get an automatic flag for that kind of thing happening.

Comment: I posted a solution to 3 different questions/threads.  The actual answer, the code, is in one place only.  My deleted answer merely links to the page that has my answer/code. I have no control over the duplication problem, obviously.

Comment: You don't post three identical answers to different questions.  You post one answer to one question, and close the other two as dupes.  You don't quite have enough rep to flag as a dupe, but this is how the site works; we don't want information duplicated in that fashion.

Comment: 29 edits, holy cow.  Are you *sure* it doesn't need some more?  I added a comment to the question, linking to the existing post.

Comment: Your concern about duplicates has been understood.  I just linked to the actual answer.  I can't do anything about the duplicates, obviously.  What's less bad ? a _small_ link to the actual answer, or no answer at all ?

Comment: Just don't answer duplicates, please. Once you have enough reputation, you can flag questions which have an adequate duplicate target.

Comment: Your link is appreciated, Hans, but there's absolutely no explanation as to what it might be, just a bunch of numbers.  Sure, duplicates are bad, but _not_ answering the question is even worse, in my opinion.  You are chasing people away, I assure you.  Is that what you want, really ?

Comment: No, it's not.  Answering duplicates just makes it harder to find answers; duplicates are kept so that future readers are directed to a high quality answer.  A link isn't that, any way you look at it.  You would be better off letting the duplicate process work.

Answer (score 16):

Your answer consists of nothing except a link that already appeared in the question.  OP is already aware of that other question, and still having problems.

Then there's the fact that the code in the full answer you linked to is a mess.  And no, the level of comments you have in that code are not a substitute for an explanation.

Comment: As I see it, the comments alone are all you need to answer the question, Ben; you could completely ignore the code that I posted.  Why you think otherwise completely baffles me; perhaps you don't understand the question or the answer.

Comment: @JeffRelf You say you were looking for reasons as to why your answer was deleted.  Are you actually open to it being incorrect, or do you prefer just arguing with everyone?

Comment: @JeffRelf: Pretty sure I understand the answer better than you like.  It violates strict aliasing.  It is not thread-safe.  It has race conditions with actual usage of the OSK.  It has hard-coded buffer sizes, which will probably break on localized Windows installs.  It mixes the task it is performing with the hotkey you personally use to launch it.  And there are zero comments explaining the peculiar behavior of the thing it's controlling.

Comment: The code works, Ben, I'm using it right now.  My idea is _very_ simple:  Check to see if the keyboard is down and, if it is, kill the keyboard processes and relaunch them before bringing the keyboard up again.  I provide a solution while you talk about "not thread-safe", as if anyone but you cared. I'm talking about the "touch keyboard" not the OSK.  Do you know the difference ?

Comment: @JeffRelf: It would really benefit from a couple sentences on detecting if the keyboard is down.  Right now it looks like you are fetching the window size of the keyboard and checking if width and height are both zero?

Comment: Yes, I'm using "IFrameworkInputPane.Location()", Ben; and, yes, that's how it works.  What kind of comment would you put there ?

Comment: @JeffRelf: Something along the lines of "Sometimes TabTip.exe is already running, but the keyboard is not responding or has zero size.  We detect these cases using `IFrameworkInputPane` COM calls, kill the existing instance, and start a new one."   Introducing code with a three-to-four sentence overview of what code does in plain English, does wonders in making the answer valuable to others.

Comment: @JeffRelf: The critical thing is that right now, unless you happen to have memorized the order of fields in `RECT`, you couldn't tell that the condition is equivalent to `rc.width == 0 && rc.height == 0`.  The strict-aliasing violation makes the code harder to understand and less correct, for no benefit.  I should think that a keyboard with zero width OR zero height is unusable, even if the other dimension is normal.

Comment: I agree, Ben, that's why I recently edited it to say: The keyboard toggle ( ITipInvocation.Toggle() ) does NOT ( N O T ) always bring up the "touch keyboard" ( Win10 DesktopMode Ver 1803 ). The solution: Check to see if the keyboard is down and, if it is, kill the keyboard processes and relaunch them before bringing the keyboard up again. This solution has been tested by me, over several days, and confirmed to work every time, no ( R A N D O M ) stalling.

Comment: @JeffRelf: Unfortunately that comment is an eyesore (what possible purpose could you have for repeating the word "not"?  It leaves the reader wondering if you mean a double negative or not), and "keyboard is down" isn't very informative.  You should list out the failure modes you are looking for.

Comment: "unsigned __int64  u[2]" is the same size as "RECT", Ben; both are 4 ints: top, left, bottom, right.

Comment: Thanks, Ben, I made the changes. I added a comment in the in the code: << "__int64 u[2]" is the same size as "RECT"; both are four 32 bit ints: top, left, bottom, right. >>  and: << The solution: use IFrameworkInputPane.Location() to see if the keyboard is "down" ( off screen ) and, if it is, kill the keyboard processes and relaunch them before bringing the keyboard up again. >>

Comment: By the way, Ben, I'm using Unicode, wchar.  Also, it doesn't really matter how you kill/launch processes; do it anyway you want.

Comment: I think my recently modified answer is worthy of undeletion; see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51396467/5732431

Comment: Personally, I only care about the solution -- how it runs;
everyone else, on the other hand, _ D E L E T E S _ anything
that's not simple, sweet, and easy to understand.

Comment: @JeffRelf: Your answer was deleted by a diamond moderator.  If it were deleted by user-moderators, I and other user-moderators could reverse it.  But diamond moderator actions can only be reversed by diamond moderators.

Comment: Thanks Ben, but my UnDeleted answer is about to get deleted as well.
StackOverflow has many agendas, none of which are worth mentioning,
and this puts "working code" low on the list, if not outright deleted.

Comment: @JeffRelf: Trust me, I've seen the good, the bad, and the ugly side of StackOverflow, many times.  But it is true, "sweet, simply, and easy to understand" is valued here, especially "easy to understand".  Because StackOverflow is a question & answer site, not a code sharing site.  The explanation really is more important than "working code".

Comment: Deleting valid answers serves someone's agenda, Ben, but it has nothing to do with "clear answers".   I think my answer is clear now, even without the code.  You've been a great help, but this site isn't for me.

Comment: '*I think my answer is clear now, even without the code.*' - Clearly, a lot of the community disagrees with you on this and this site is community driven and what is this secret agenda that you speak of?